# When the cursor is moved to the right of the SWT table the horizontal bar is not moved to right of the column selected

Tags: swt, horizontal-scrolling

I have converted the existing SWT table to excel sheet but when the cursor is moved to the right of the table(i.e out of the table in current view) the horizontal bar is not shifted to right, but the vertical movement is happening fine.

I read somewhere that the horizontal movement is not possible for SWT table.

```
public void addTreeNavigationBehavior(final Tree treeComposite){
        final TreeCursor cursor = new TreeCursor(treeComposite, SWT.NONE);

        final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(treeComposite, SWT.NONE);

        final ControlEditor editor = new ControlEditor(cursor);
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.grabVertical = true;
        cursor.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            // when the TableEditor is over a cell, select the corresponding row in 
            // the table
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
//              cursor.scroll(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);
                //need to attach the a method to this say is selectable 
                scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
                treeComposite.setSelection(cursor.getRow());
//              treeComposite.getHorizontalBar().setSelection(cursor.getColumn());
//              cursor.getHorizontalBar().setSelection(cursor.getColumn());

            }
            // when the user hits "ENTER" in the TableCursor, pop up a text editor so that 
            // they can change the text of the cell
            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                final Text text = new Text(cursor, SWT.NONE);
                TreeItem row = cursor.getRow();
                int column = cursor.getColumn();
                text.setText(row.getText(column));
                text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                        // close the text editor and copy the data over 
                        // when the user hits "ENTER"
                        if (e.character == SWT.CR) {
                            TreeItem row = cursor.getRow();
                            int column = cursor.getColumn();
                            row.setText(column, text.getText());
                            text.dispose();
                        }
                        // close the text editor when the user hits "ESC"
                        if (e.character == SWT.ESC) {
                            text.dispose();
                        }
                    }
                });
                // close the text editor when the user tabs away
                text.addFocusListener(new org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                        text.dispose();
                    }
                });
                editor.setEditor(text);
                text.setFocus();
            }
        });
        // Hide the TableCursor when the user hits the "CTRL" or "SHIFT" key.
        // This allows the user to select multiple items in the table.
        cursor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.keyCode == SWT.CTRL
                    || e.keyCode == SWT.SHIFT
                    || (e.stateMask & SWT.CONTROL) != 0
                    || (e.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT) != 0) {
                    cursor.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        // When the user double clicks in the TableCursor, pop up a text editor so that 
        // they can change the text of the cell.
        cursor.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                final Text text = new Text(cursor, SWT.NONE);
                TreeItem row = cursor.getRow();
                int column = cursor.getColumn();
                text.setText(row.getText(column));
                text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                        // close the text editor and copy the data over 
                        // when the user hits "ENTER"
                        if (e.character == SWT.CR) {
                            TreeItem row = cursor.getRow();
                            int column = cursor.getColumn();
                            row.setText(column, text.getText());
                            text.dispose();
                        }
                        // close the text editor when the user hits "ESC"
                        if (e.character == SWT.ESC) {
                            text.dispose();
                        }
                    }
                });
                // close the text editor when the user clicks away
                text.addFocusListener(new org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                        text.dispose();
                    }
                });
                editor.setEditor(text);
                text.setFocus();
            }
        });

        // Show the TableCursor when the user releases the "SHIFT" or "CTRL" key.
        // This signals the end of the multiple selection task.
        treeComposite.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.keyCode == SWT.CONTROL && (e.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT) != 0) return;
                if (e.keyCode == SWT.SHIFT && (e.stateMask & SWT.CONTROL) != 0) return;
                if (e.keyCode != SWT.CONTROL && (e.stateMask & SWT.CONTROL) != 0) return;
                if (e.keyCode != SWT.SHIFT && (e.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT) != 0) return;

                TreeItem[] selection = treeComposite.getSelection();
                TreeItem row = (selection.length == 0) ? treeComposite.getTopItem() : selection[0];
                treeComposite.showItem(row);
                cursor.setSelection(row, cursor.getColumn());
                cursor.setVisible(true);
                cursor.setFocus();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Add snap shot and code.

Comment: I have not coded any thing explicitly for horizontal or vertical movement. I just need to know why vertical is working and horizontal not.

Comment: @user1719010 But we need to see your code to be able to reproduce your problem and come up with a solution.